# React native, registerHeadlessTask does not call my function

Tags: android, react-native, headless

The notification appears on the top (The app is running....) but the function is not getting called. I can't find any error. Anyone knows what might be causing the issue?
I create a package and add it like this packages.add(new BackgroundPackage());

This is my index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
const MyHeadlessTask = async () => {
  console.log('Should be headless');//<--this is not getting called
};

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('Background', () => MyHeadlessTask);//<<--this
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.printerandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <service
            android:name="com.printerandroid.BackgroundService" >
        </service>
      <service android:name="com.printerandroid.BackgroundEventService"/>
      <receiver
            android:name="com.printerandroid.BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must register component like this

```
function MyHeadlessTask({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}

function App() {
  // Your application
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => MyHeadlessTask);
```

Also, don't forget to make the changes as mentioned [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state).

Comment: I doesn't work. It only works when the GUI is open.

Comment: Did you make the changes to AppDelete as mentioned in https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state